# Prevent losing focus of ScrollView element while scrolling ScrollView

Tags: android, focus, scrollview, selected

Lets say I have some Button objects (View) inside my HorizontalScrollView. When I press one of them, I set a focus to it (it is being highlighted):

```
    Button candidateButton = (Button) v;
    v.requestFocusFromTouch();
    v.setSelected(true);
```

Then, when I scroll HorizontalScrollView - highlighting disappears. I would like to keep focus on my button (View). Can anyone help?